# Write to Organic groups

Tags: organic-groups

I need option like on Facebook groups to publish something in group, and then user comment that.

Now i have only comment form which users use to post in groups.

I need something like posting nodes, but in group.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can allow any content type as content in the group. So if you want to set post in group you can edit **post** content type and make as group content.

When you edit the **post** content type usign **admin>structure>content types>post** you will find the following options to add this content type as group option.

[image]

After doing this when you  visit post create page you will find group select box. From here you can select the group.

Comment: And then how do i show that node in group? I created content type, added node, but now i dont know how to insert it in group? Thank you!

Comment: if you are using page manager, panel and organic group module then there will be page called **node_view** you have to enable it. flush cache and visit the group node

Comment: And one more thing there will be view named **OG content** you can view it and pass the group id to view the output

Comment: Hi, where will node_view appear? Yes i see OG Content, should i call it in node--group or? Thank you!

Comment: in **admin/structure/pages** you will find node_view it contains all the things in panel like latest posts, members list, add content link etc..

Comment: Yes, i enabled node_view and flushed cache. But still there is no content in group node. One more thing, i dont know how to implement view OG content in group?

Comment: Ok, its working now. I associate content type to group and i displayed nodes in group.

But when i create node in content type, i want to redirect user to group.

Not to node that is just created.

I need only this.

Thank you!

Comment: You can implement custom form alter and redirect to group node..and if u find helpful please accept the answer and upvote..